# Identifying single-row subquery error

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have an Oracle SQL query that's throwing the error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

What can I do to avoid this error? What can I do to identify the cause/source of this error?

Here's the SQL query:

```
  select (select CID 
          from SPL A
          where A.prodid = appl.prod_id
                    and A.STATUS = 'SET'
                    and A.DT = (select min(DT) from SPL B where A.prodid = B.prodid))
            as CIDORIG
  from prod_master appl
  where prod_status = 'OFF';
```

However, I'm unable to locate such a subquery in my SQL statement. A MIN() returns only one result. I also tried replacing the '=' sign with the keyword IN, but without any luck. This query works for other prod_status values.

It fetches 13,700 rows out of the 15,648 rows that we are expecting, before throwing the error. I'm expecting 15,648 rows because SQL Developer is configured to return only 50 rows at a time. When I select the option "Count Rows", it gives me the number 15,648.

SPL and prod_master are both views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the subquery that returns more than one row is:

```
     (select CID 
      from SPL A
      where A.prodid = appl.prod_id
                and A.STATUS = 'SET'
                and A.DT = (select min(DT) from SPL B where A.prodid = B.prodid)
     ) as CIDORIG
```

To fix this, try choosing `min(CID)` or `max(CID)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Scalar sub-queries only if you are sure that your sub-query is going to return 1 or 0 rows, other wise you will end up with this error.

You can write you query without using scalar sub-query as follows

```
select a.CID 
  from prod_master appl
       join SPL A
         on ( A.prodid = appl.prod_id)
  where appl.prod_status = 'OFF'
    and A.STATUS = 'SET'
    and A.DT = (select min(b.DT) 
                  from SPL B 
                 where A.prodid = B.prodid);
```